# how to save image from url using php and replace if already exist

Tags: php, mysql, image

i am trying to save a video thumbnail from dailymotion i can bring the image URL but the actual problem i am getting is to save that thumbnail on my server by renaming image. Secondly i want to check that name if the name is already exist on the server it can replace the older one this function is basically used on updating video id.

Here is my php code to grab dailymotion video thumbnail url but i don't know to to save it

```
<?php
$related_dm_code = "x2rxn6i"; //Video Code
$thumbd_item='https://api.dailymotion.com/video/'.$related_dm_code.'?fields=thumbnail_240_url';
$json_thumbnail2_item = file_get_contents($thumbd_item);
$get_thumbnail2_item = json_decode($json_thumbnail2_item, TRUE);
$thumb2_item=$get_thumbnail2_item['thumbnail_240_url'];
echo $thumb2_item; //display thumbnail url
?>
```

e.g. here is the thumbnail url:

> anothersite.com/images/demo-image.jpg

How can i save image in this path of my URL:

> mysite.com/video_thumbs/

and renaming **demo-image.jpg** to **anyothername.jpg**

and then a last part of the function to check and replace if **anyothername.jpg** is already exist then replace with the older one this would be used to updating mysql

Comment: you're already using the solution: `file_get_contents()`, and then you can save the fetched data with `file_put_contents()`, which will put the data anywhere you want, with whatever name you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like:

```
if (!file_exists('http://www.example.com/video_thumbs/' . $file)) {
   $img = file_get_contents("http://www.anothersite.com/images/demo-image.jpg");

   file_put_contents('http://www.example.com/video_thumbs/' . $file, $img);
}
```

Comment: **file_put_contents** works for me but how can i check for the update if already exist then replace it?

Comment: Every image must have a name so you can identify later (id of the video or something else). So when you use your code, it will check if that file name already exists on your server. You can also use `sha1_file()` function to check if they are the same image before update. Let me know if i wasn't clear on something or if misunderstood what you are trying to achieve.